# How to make Boost::GIL work with PNG & JPEG IO?

Tags: boost, build, png, jpeg, boost-gil

Boost::GIL has almost perfect tutorial and manual. I find it troublesome to lack guide on building and using Boost::GIL work with PNG & JPEG IO. Does anyone have experience or have successfully did that? Please kindly advise! Thanks!

### EDIT:

Answer lies here: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/gil/Downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used GIL successfully with JPEG.

I assume that you have downloaded and included the boost::gil headers.

The jpeg library is NOT included in the boost library.

The simplest thing is to include and link to one of the many copies of the jpeg library that are distributed.  I use the one with wxWidgets ( wxWidgets-2.8.10\src\jpeg ).  If you search your disk for the file jconfig.h, you should find a configured and built jpeg library that will work for you.

You can download the jpeg library source from http://www.ijg.org/ but then you will have to configure it for your platform and build it.

Comment: No. I haven't. What version of JPEG do you use? Can it be as simple as just including headers? What about build flags? Could you please share those details (including & building). Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what about PNG? I got problem with PNG! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442335/libpng-boostgil-png-infopp-null-not-found

Comment: By the way, image formats implementation for Boost.GIL has been redesigned and it's currently being reviewed to be included in the official Boost.GIL release. http://mateusz.loskot.net/?p=2117